# Planes have textures, but no UV maps

Tags: uv

I made a curve that used planes that were UV mapped into a mesh and now the mesh has no UV map so it can't have materials added to it in Unity. I'm looking for a solution that let's me keep the textures as they are and gives the mesh a UV map.

Comment: Please add some images to your question. It's difficult to understand what you are asking without images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.